# How to dynamically map URLs to Java servlet handlers based on their names? (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, url-routing, java-server

What I'm looking for is some sort of class or annotation I can add to Java classes that are dedicated to handling specific requests, and having URLs map to these based on their name. For example, have the URL ".../api/GetContactsRequest" map to a handler named GetContactsRequest (or 404 if no such handler exists). I know I could write servlets and map each URL to each servlet, but I figure the less boilerplate routing code/configuration, the better! These will mostly be application request handlers, communicating using JSON. I haven't figured out how I'll be handling static requests, but I'll most likely just be sending a big web application at the user that navigates itself or something.

For background, I'm using the Google App Engine so I have access to yaml configurations and their servlet APIs. So is there a standard way of doing this with either the Java servlet APIs or the Google App Engine-specific framework? I've only ever used specific Java servlet frameworks like Apache and stuff before, which were all already built by the time I started working on them, so I really don't know what there is to use with this environment. I'm also new to this all in general, and having trouble wading through what Servlets, Services, Filters, Listeners, and Handlers all are, and which is best for this simple routing behavior that I want/need. I'm worried I'll pick the wrong one, or don't even know of the one that would suit my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [`JAX-RS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) does - not exactly class name mapping, but mapping via annotations. See [some of the features](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features).

There are several implementations, personally I use [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) - it works flawlessly on GAE. Additionally I use Jackson (comes with RESTEasy) to produce JSON.

If you need to produce html then look at [`htmleasy`](http://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/) - it's a thin layer on top of RESTEasy enabling use of different html templating libraries. It'll help you separate logic from presentation.

**EDIT:**

If you really want to avoid using standard libs and writing something on your own, then write a servlet filter that inspects the request and forwards it to your servlet (or invoke custom code):

```
public class ForwardFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {

        if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/some/path")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/path/where/servlet/registered").forward(request, response);
            return; // prevents normal request processing

        }

        // you need this for normal request path
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there really no way built into either Java or GAE as is? The less third-party code I have to add and understand, the better! Especially since adding libraries usually means more boilerplate.

Comment: One of the axioms of successful coders is "stand on the shoulders of giants", meaning reuse code that other smart people have made. Actually, writing code where others have already sufficiently solved the problem is considered a big mistake in programming (aka reinventing the wheel). You should not fret using 3rd party libraries, especially if they are standards based (JAX-RS is a Java standard), open-sourced and supported by reputable people/companies.

Comment: I understand that, but at the same time, I just want to make sure I'm not adding anything unnecessary, i.e. if what I wanted already existed in standard Java or GAE. I looked into it a bit more, and feel more comfortable about it if it is considered a standard library. Thanks! :)